# Import Tensorflow and Keras crashing Django App With error "Process finished with exit code 252"

Tags: python, django, tensorflow, keras, pycharm

I'm trying to load a pre-trained keras model in django application and facing this issue.

Import of Keras or Tensorflow packages crashing the django app while running.

No errors found in the console of pycharm editor.

I can see only message "Process finished with exit code 252"

Python version: 3.8
Django version: 3.2.4
Keras version: 2.13.1
Tensorflow version: 2.13.0
OS: Mac OS
IDE: Pycharm

Please help me to run the django app.